# Access PIVOT from SQL Syntax

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2003

I'm using Access and I'm trying to duplicate a rather complex pivot table I had in SQL and it seems to be having an issue with the FROM statement in the syntax.

```
SELECT r.resourceName AS 'Resource Name', 
    p.projectNumber AS 'Project Number', 
    p.projectName AS 'Project Name', 
    p.projectSystem AS 'Project System', 
    a.resourceProjRole AS 'Resource Role', 
    p.projectManager AS 'Project Manager', 
    a.allocDescription AS 'Description', 
    a.[Sep 2014], a.[Oct 2014], 
    a.[Nov 2014], a.[Dec 2014]
FROM Projects p, Resources r 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM allocation a 
PIVOT (SUM(allocationValue) 
FOR AllocationMonth IN ([Sep 2014], [Oct 2014], [Nov 2014], [Dec 2014] )) PVT ) a 
ON (r.resourceName = a.resourceName)WHERE p.projectName = a.projectName ORDER BY r.resourceName, a.projectName
```

This is what I managed so far

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Allocation.AllocationValue)
SELECT Allocation.ProjectName
FROM Allocation
GROUP BY Allocation.ProjectName
PIVOT Allocation.AllocationMonth IN ('June, 2014', 'July, 2014')
```

This somewhat works as it lists the values by their month but I need it to break it down by ResourceName as well, right now it calculates all values only according to their project.

Comment: It looks like you are using the SQL Server syntax for pivot, instead of the [access syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192901%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I'm having trouble converting it over to Access Syntax using transform.  I never used Access before and I'm wondering if anyone could shed some light on it.

Comment: I edited the question to include my attempt so far. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: What is the error you get for this (note: I don't use Access myself, so I will only be able to provide limited help. However my first guess would be to replace the quotes around the names in the `IN` clause by square brackets (`[` and `]`).

Comment: The syntax works fine so far, I just can't get it incorporate the columns I need.  I need it to order it by ResourceName first then ProjectName, but when I try to add the ResourceName or any other field it gives me "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'resourceName' as part of an aggregate function" @MarkRotteveel

Comment: If you want to use the order by, you must include those columns also in the group by (you may even have to include them in the select).

Comment: Adding them in the select by is what gives me the error.

Comment: But did you include them in the group by as well?

Comment: Wow, I feel silly but that did the trick, I could of sworn I had that before but I didn't.  Thanks for your time!